# iframe with flash content floats over horizontal menu when scrolling down the website in IE9

Tags: iframe, scroll, internet-explorer-9, z-index

I'm trying to load an `<iframe>` which has a flash file embeded. I can't use the `object/embed` tag because the flash won't play in iPhone/iPad unless it sits inside an `<iframe>`. When I'm scrolling down the page in IE 9, I notice that the `<iframe>` floats over the horizontal main menu which has a fixed position on the page. Is there any way to solve this problem, to force the `<iframe>` content go under the main menu? Here's my code for the `<iframe>`:

```
<iframe name="flash object" src="http://www.website.com/flash.html?>" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" height="380" width="100%">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add in the flash swf file:

> wmode="transparent"

This will transparent the swf file and resolve the issue.
[Transparent background in a SWF file](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/transparent-background-swf-file.html)

For your new Question, I made you a small script that you can change flash on the fly this script does only console.log you will have to assign it to your flash:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var swfPaths = ['swf1.swf','swf2.swf','swf3.swf','swf4.swf'];
    var oSwfs = [];
    for(i=0; i < swfPaths.length; i++){oSwfs[i] = swfPaths[i];}
    curSwf = Math.floor(Math.random()*oSwfs.length);
    window.onload=function(){
        console.log(oSwfs[curSwf]);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This does the work, but I would need to edit all html files which are dynamically played by the iframe. Every time I refresh the page I need a different flash file to be loaded in the iframe. Is there a way to fix this inside the html code which includes the iframe? thanks

Comment: Yes you can do that, Please can you tell me do you have predefined flash files you want to show? i mean list of flash files you want.

Comment: Please can you paste here the SWF script that you are using inside the iframe so i make u a small javascript to change the swf file on each refresh.

Comment: I'm using php to fetch the paths for the .swf files on every page refresh. I managed to solve this problem by creating a template file for all my .swf files in the software I'm using to generate them. So I won't have to edit them one by one from now on. My code is working fine now, thanks for your help.